# to fix bugs in Android studio

Tags: java, android

I want you to know I'm a newbie to `Android Development`.

I have developed an `Android application`. Before releasing the app I tested it many times on my device and several others to check if it crashes or not. The app passed all the tests.

Now the app is crashing on some of the user's device and how to know reason of crashing app of the user's device.
 I'm a bit confused about how to tackle problems like this.

```
private static void logInitError(@NonNull String message) {
        CrashLog.log(message);
        CrashLog.log(locationManager == null ? "!!! NOT INITIALISED !!!" : "locationManager initialised");
        DebugTestException debugException = new DebugTestException();
        CrashLog.logException(debugException);
    }

    private static void logInitErrorNoProvider(@NonNull String message) {
        CrashLog.log(message);
        CrashLog.log(locationManager == null ? "!!! NOT INITIALISED !!!" : "locationManager initialised");
        DebugTestException debugException = new DebugTestException();
        CrashLog.logException(debugException);
    }
```

Comment: install crashlytics..

Comment: @ShivamOberoi i think you mean `Crashlytics`

Comment: fabric is deprecated in favor of firebase crashlytics, use that

Comment: without using crashlytices..can I fix

Comment: @Sush : If you don't want to hear Crashlytics as an answer you should specify your requirements in your question, especially those that are incompatible with it

Comment: I know about Firebase Crashlytics. i will try thank u

Answer (score 0):

The best way to monitor the app is to use firebase crashlytics.

You will get real-time analytics from your app, refer [the official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/) for implementation.